# How to visit a page in my Firefox profile using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm want to visit a lit of URLs (about 3000) so I can add them to my browser history in Firefox. I'm trying to do with Selenium but it's not working.

```
name = "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2ccgbbg0.default"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=name)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

The program takes minutes to make the profile and produces the following error when trying to make the driver.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Default/Documents/selenium_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 166, in __init__
    capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\options.py", line 180, in to_capabilities
    opts["profile"] = self._profile.encoded
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 180, in encoded
    return base64.b64encode(fp.getvalue()).decode('UTF-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
MemoryError
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a memory issue related to the size of your firefox profile.
Check the size of `"C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2ccgbbg0.default"`

Also, try monitoring your ram usage while trying to run it.

Another possibility would be the versions of firefox/geckodriver/python/selenium you're using being too old.